# Update plot according to updated slider value wit Gtk

Tags: slider, gtk, julia

In Julia, I'd like to update a plot upon the change of value in a Gtk Slider. I understand that this has to do with the "change-value" signal in https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkRange.html#GtkRange-value-changed. However, as a beginner, I do not know how to implement the code

```
The “change-value” signal
gboolean
user_function (GtkRange     *range,
               GtkScrollType scroll,
               gdouble       value,
               gpointer      user_data)
```

to achieve what I wanted to do. Could anyone kindly provide an example how to use the "change-value" signal?

I know how to set up a window for the slider

```
sl = slider(1:11)
win = Window("Testing") |> (bx = Box(:v))
push!(bx, sl)
Gtk.showall(win)
```

I also know what kind of function I need to update the plot

```
function update(val)
    int_val = int(val)
    if Signal(sl) != int_val
        x = range(0., 2*pi, step=0.01)
        y = map(sin, x)
        PyPlot.plot(x,Signal(sl)*y)
    end
end
```

However, I don't know how or where I can trigger the "update" function to take actual action.

Thanks!

Comment: a minimal working example (MWE) would be useful.

Comment: You're supposed to connect a callback to the `change-value` signal of the slider, and in that callback, call your `update` function. Here's some documentation on [julia and GTK+](http://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/signals.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, liberforce for your advice!
Here is my minimal working example:
'''

```
using Gtk

# Set up scale (slider) and window
sl = GtkScale(false, 0:10)
win = Gtk.Window("Gain Selection") |> (bx = Gtk.Box(:v))
push!(bx, sl)
Gtk.showall(win)

# Connect with value-changed signal
id = signal_connect(sl, "value-changed") do widget
    # Get scale value
    sub = Gtk.GAccessor.adjustment(widget)
    val = Gtk.get_gtk_property(sub,"value",Int64)
    # Perform function related to the scale value.
    println("Gain is changed to ", val)
end
push!(bx, sl)
Gtk.showall(win);
```

'''

Reference:
signal connect: http://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/signals.html

GtkScale: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Scale.html

Extract scale value: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-get-the-current-value-of-a-gtk-scale-widget/15680

Julia Do-block: https://www.juliabloggers.com/julia-do-block-vs-python-with-statement/